# case-insensitive regular expressions

Tags: regex, haskell, case-insensitive

What's the best way to use regular expressions with options (flags) in Haskell

I use

```
Text.Regex.PCRE
```

The documentation lists a few interesting options like compCaseless, compUTF8, ...
But I don't know how to use them with (=~)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All the `Text.Regex.*` modules make heavy use of typeclasses, which are there for extensibility and "overloading"-like behavior, but make usage less obvious from just seeing types.

Now, you've probably been started off from the basic `=~` matcher.

```
(=~) ::
  ( RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption source
  , RegexContext Regex source1 target )
  => source1 -> source -> target
(=~~) ::
  ( RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption source
  , RegexContext Regex source1 target, Monad m )
  => source1 -> source -> m target
```

To use `=~`, there must exist an instance of `RegexMaker ...` for the LHS, and `RegexContext ...` for the RHS and result.

```
class RegexOptions regex compOpt execOpt | ...
      | regex -> compOpt execOpt
      , compOpt -> regex execOpt
      , execOpt -> regex compOpt
class RegexOptions regex compOpt execOpt
      => RegexMaker regex compOpt execOpt source
         | regex -> compOpt execOpt
         , compOpt -> regex execOpt
         , execOpt -> regex compOpt
  where
    makeRegex :: source -> regex
    makeRegexOpts :: compOpt -> execOpt -> source -> regex
```

A valid instance of all these classes (for example, `regex=Regex`, `compOpt=CompOption`, `execOpt=ExecOption`, and `source=String`) means it's possible to compile a `regex` with `compOpt,execOpt` options from some form `source`.  (Also, given some `regex` type, there is exactly one `compOpt,execOpt` set that goes along with it.  Lots of different `source` types are okay, though.)

```
class Extract source
class Extract source
      => RegexLike regex source
class RegexLike regex source
      => RegexContext regex source target
  where
    match :: regex -> source -> target
    matchM :: Monad m => regex -> source -> m target
```

A valid instance of all these classes (for example, `regex=Regex`, `source=String`, `target=Bool`) means it's possible to match a `source` and a `regex` to yield a `target`.  (Other valid `target`s given these specific `regex` and `source` are `Int`, `MatchResult String`, `MatchArray`, etc.)

Put these together and it's pretty obvious that `=~` and `=~~` are simply convenience functions

```
source1 =~ source
  = match (makeRegex source) source1
source1 =~~ source
  = matchM (makeRegex source) source1
```

and also that `=~` and `=~~` leave no room to pass various options to `makeRegexOpts`.

You could make your own

```
(=~+) ::
   ( RegexMaker regex compOpt execOpt source
   , RegexContext regex source1 target )
   => source1 -> (source, compOpt, execOpt) -> target
source1 =~+ (source, compOpt, execOpt)
  = match (makeRegexOpts compOpt execOpt source) source1
(=~~+) ::
   ( RegexMaker regex compOpt execOpt source
   , RegexContext regex source1 target, Monad m )
   => source1 -> (source, compOpt, execOpt) -> m target
source1 =~~+ (source, compOpt, execOpt)
  = matchM (makeRegexOpts compOpt execOpt source) source1
```

which could be used like

```
"string" =~+ ("regex", CompCaseless + compUTF8, execBlank) :: Bool
```

or overwrite `=~` and `=~~` with methods which can accept options

```
import Text.Regex.PCRE hiding ((=~), (=~~))

class RegexSourceLike regex source
  where
    makeRegexWith source :: source -> regex
instance RegexMaker regex compOpt execOpt source
         => RegexSourceLike regex source
  where
    makeRegexWith = makeRegex
instance RegexMaker regex compOpt execOpt source
         => RegexSourceLike regex (source, compOpt, execOpt)
  where
    makeRegexWith (source, compOpt, execOpt)
      = makeRegexOpts compOpt execOpt source

source1 =~ source
  = match (makeRegexWith source) source1
source1 =~~ source
  = matchM (makeRegexWith source) source1
```

or you could just use `match`, `makeRegexOpts`, etc. directly where needed.

Comment: Ah, it seems that I've been beat to the solution.  That's what I get for writing all sorts of unnecessary stuff :-/

Comment: Ah, I feel a little guilty now, yours certainly offers a much more comprehensive overview! I like you suggestion for (=~+) by the way.

Comment: it's a very complete and comprehensive answer indeed, I'd like to reward the effort, but I don't know if it's common practice to switch the "accepted answer" ? anyway, I'm new to Haskell, and this answer really helped me to understand some clever principles of the language (also, little typo at the begining you wrote =~ instead of =~~ )

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to switch the accepted answer when a new and better answer is given.  Though I must say that (?i) is a whole lot less typing.

Comment: Right, I don't have Text.Regex.PCRE installed, and I wasn't thinking of that.  This solution (or something very similar) should work for anything from Text.Regex.*.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know anything about Haskell, but if you're using a regex library based on PCRE, then you can use mode modifiers inside the regular expression.  To match "caseless" in a case insensitive fashion, you can use this regex in PCRE:

```
(?i)caseless
```

The mode modifier (?i) overrides any case sensitivity or case insensitivity option that was set outside the regular expression.  It also works with operators that don't allow you to set any options.

Similarly, (?s) turns on "single line mode" which makes the dot match line breaks, (?m) turns on "multi line mode" which makes ^ and $ match at line breaks, and (?x) turns on free-spacing mode (unescaped spaces and line breaks outside character classes are insignificant).  You can combine the letters.  (?ismx) turns on everything.  A hyphen turns off options. (?-i) makes the regex case sensitive.  (?x-i) starts a free-spacing case sensitive regex.

Comment: it works too ! it's much simpler but also less generic than the accepted solution

Comment: +1 This allows us to keep the idomatic `=~` operator and make the regex defined as a `String`. Much more basic!

Answer (score 9):

I believe cannot use (=~) if you wish to use `compOpt` other than `defaultCompOpt`.

Something like this work:

```
match (makeRegexOpts compCaseless defaultExecOpt  "(Foo)" :: Regex) "foo" :: Bool
```

The follow two articles should assist you:

[Real World Haskell, Chapter 8. Efficient file processing, regular expressions, and file name matching](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html)

[A Haskell regular expression tutorial](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/02/27/a-haskell-regular-expression-tutorial/)