# Haskell: scary type signature

Tags: haskell

I'm struggling to understand this type signature:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> :t (=~)
(=~)
  :: (Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike.RegexMaker
        Regex CompOption ExecOption source,
      Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike.RegexContext Regex source1 target) =>
     source1 -> source -> target
```

I reckon they list type classes, `source`, `source1` and `target` should be instances of, but the semantics look completely arcane (that is, I would not be able to replicate it, even if I understood what it says).

Comment: =~ is polymorphic in its return type as well as in its arguments' types.  That means if you are expecting a boolean, it will return a boolean.  If you are expecting a list of strings, it will return a list of the captures.  Etc.  (The polymorphic argument type is so that you can match both Strings and ByteStrings, for example.)

Comment: That doesn't help me to understand the context definition part. `source` should be instance of what type class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing strange going on here: just some type classes with a lot of arguments. (The long `Text.Regex.Base...` module names don't help, either.)

- There must be a [`RegexMaker`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/latest/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#v:RegexMaker) instance for: `Regex`, `CompOption`, `ExecOption`, and whatever type `source` is
- There must be a [`RegexContext`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/latest/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#v:RegexContext) instance for: `Regex`, whatever type `source1` is, and whatever type `target` is
- The `(=~)` function itself takes a `source1` and a `source` and gives a `target`

Haskell's own `(+)` operator is a similar shape to `(=~)`, but its type is hopefully easier to read:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Comment: I don't get it. Perhaps I'm too noob yet. I am in the middle of this chapter at the moment: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html

Comment: Do you understand how to use type classes themselves? That is, do you know the significance of `Num a` in my `(+)` type above?

Comment: But I wouldn't if there were say `Num SomeOtherType a`

Comment: But `Num SomeOtherType a` isn't valid syntax, since the `Num` type class only accepts one type argument. The `RegexMaker` type class, on the other hand, accepts four type arguments, so that's why it looks different.

Comment: Ok, it is more clear how to read it now. However, if `Num a` makes perfect sense in the way that "type `a` must be instance of `Num`" then it is still unclear what would be the meaning of say `Class1 Class2 a` (looks like I can't get my head around some basic conception or something)

Comment: I had the same confusion the first time I saw a type class with more than one argument. I would read it as: `Num a` = "there must be an instance of `Num` with parameter `a`"... `Class1 Class2 a` = "there must be an instance of `Class1` with parameters `Class2` and `a`"

Comment: Things start taking shape. Thanks!

Comment: Np! Luckily this sort of multi-parameter type class (or at least the kind with 4 or more parameters) is comparatively rare.

Comment: Multi-parameter type classes require a Haskell extension called MultiParamTypeClasses to be enabled. You can actually use the multi-parameter type class in modules that don't enable the extension as long as the class and all the instances you're using are defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a fairly thorough description of the Text.Regex typeclasses in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007846/1008334#1008334).

Copying most of that here...

---

All the `Text.Regex.*` modules make heavy use of typeclasses, which are there for extensibility and "overloading"-like behavior, but make usage less obvious from just seeing types.

Now, you've probably been started off from the basic `=~` matcher.

```
(=~) ::
  ( RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption source
  , RegexContext Regex source1 target )
  => source1 -> source -> target
(=~~) ::
  ( RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption source
  , RegexContext Regex source1 target, Monad m )
  => source1 -> source -> m target
```

To use `=~`, there must exist an instance of `RegexMaker ...` for the LHS, and `RegexContext ...` for the RHS and result.

```
class RegexOptions regex compOpt execOpt | ...
      | regex -> compOpt execOpt
      , compOpt -> regex execOpt
      , execOpt -> regex compOpt
class RegexOptions regex compOpt execOpt
      => RegexMaker regex compOpt execOpt source
         | regex -> compOpt execOpt
         , compOpt -> regex execOpt
         , execOpt -> regex compOpt
  where
    makeRegex :: source -> regex
    makeRegexOpts :: compOpt -> execOpt -> source -> regex
```

A valid instance of all these classes (for example, `regex=Regex`, `compOpt=CompOption`, `execOpt=ExecOption`, and `source=String`) means it's possible to compile a `regex` with `compOpt,execOpt` options from some form `source`.  (Also, given some `regex` type, there is exactly one `compOpt,execOpt` set that goes along with it.  Lots of different `source` types are okay, though.)

```
class Extract source
class Extract source
      => RegexLike regex source
class RegexLike regex source
      => RegexContext regex source target
  where
    match :: regex -> source -> target
    matchM :: Monad m => regex -> source -> m target
```

A valid instance of all these classes (for example, `regex=Regex`, `source=String`, `target=Bool`) means it's possible to match a `source` and a `regex` to yield a `target`.  (Other valid `target`s given these specific `regex` and `source` are `Int`, `MatchResult String`, `MatchArray`, etc.)

Put these together and it's pretty obvious that `=~` and `=~~` are simply convenience functions

```
source1 =~ source
  = match (makeRegex source) source1
source1 =~~ source
  = matchM (makeRegex source) source1
```