# Regular expressions versus lexical analyzers in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell, lexical-analysis, alex

I'm getting started with Haskell and I'm trying to use the [Alex](http://haskell.org/alex/) tool to create regular expressions and I'm a little bit lost; my first inconvenience was the compile part. How I have to do to compile a file with Alex?. Then, I think that I have to import into my code the modules that alex generates, but not sure. If someone can help me, I would be very greatful!

Comment: Is this even a regex question? If so, you might get more reply if you tag it `regex`. It seems not, though, so maybe you will get more replies if you re-title it, something like "problems with Alex in Haskell" (is there an `Alex` tag? Is one needed?))

Comment: I personally always use Antlr for regex work, especially with AntlrWorks, which allows you to visualize and vizually debug your regular expressions. However, thid question may also be of help to you ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364259/antlr-vs-happy-vs-other-parser-generators

Answer (score 6):

You can specify regular expression functions in Alex.

Here for example, a regex in Alex to match floating point numbers:

```
$space       = [\ \t\xa0]
$digit       = 0-9
$octit       = 0-7
$hexit       = [$digit A-F a-f]

@sign        = [\-\+]
@decimal     = $digit+
@octal       = $octit+
@hexadecimal = $hexit+
@exponent    = [eE] [\-\+]? @decimal

@number      = @decimal
             | @decimal \. @decimal @exponent?
             | @decimal @exponent
             | 0[oO] @octal
             | 0[xX] @hexadecimal

lex :-

   @sign? @number { strtod }
```

When we match the floating point number, we dispatch to a parsing function to operate on that captured string, which we can then wrap and expose to the user as a parsing function:

```
readDouble :: ByteString -> Maybe (Double, ByteString)
readDouble str = case alexScan (AlexInput '\n' str) 0 of
    AlexEOF            -> Nothing
    AlexError _        -> Nothing
    AlexToken (AlexInput _ rest) n _ ->
       case strtod (B.unsafeTake n str) of d -> d `seq` Just $! (d , rest)
```

A nice consequence of using Alex for this regex matching is that the performance is good, as the regex engine is compiled statically. It can also be exposed as a regular Haskell library built with cabal. For the full implementation, see [bytestring-lexing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-lexing).

The general advice on when to use a lexer instead of a regex matcher would be that, if you have a grammar for the lexemes you're trying to match, as I did for floating point, use Alex. If you don't, and the structure is more ad hoc, use a regex engine.

Comment: Thank's Don Stewart, that is what I was looking for, because the really what I wanted to do is to create a lexical and sintatic analizer, that's why I was trying to create the regex.... Thank's everybody, you all helpt a lot :)

Comment: Sorry if Iḿ bothering you, but can you explain me a little bit the last line "case strtod (B.unsafeTake n str) of d -> d `seq` Just $! (d , rest)", cause I don't get it

Comment: Oh, that's just running 'strtod' on the lexeme, then returning the result strictly.

Comment: I took your code to see what was the result, but it gives me an error, thatś why I'd like to understand to see what itś wrong

Comment: Grab the code from the Alex examples directory, available in the source tarball for Alex.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use alex to create regular expressions?
If all you want is to do some regex matching etc, you should look at the regex-base package.

Comment: What I really want to do is a lexical and sintactic analyzer, that's why Iḿ working with alex :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is plain Regex you want, the API is specified in [text.regex.base](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.3/html/libraries/regex-base/Text-Regex-Base.html). Then there are the implementations [text.regex.Posix](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.3/html/libraries/regex-posix/Text-Regex-Posix.html) , [text.regex.pcre](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-pcre/0.81/doc/html/Text-Regex-PCRE.html) and several others. The Haddoc documentation is a bit slim, however the basics are described in [Real World Haskell, chapter 8.](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html) Some more indepth stuff is descriped in this [SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007846/haskell-case-insensitive-regular-expressions)

Comment: What I really want to do is a lexical and sintactic analyzer, that's why Iḿ working with alex :)